# Update a global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, global

I have a problem with my 2 js files and two html files main.html and log.html with only one button that redirect to main.html and throw an alert

JS File 1:
I have a global variable

```
context= {};
```

and a main:

`function main() { 
  if (typeof context.active != 'undefined')
       alert(context.active); 
}`

JS File 2:

I have a function

`function setActive() {
   context.active=true;
   window.location.href="main.html";
}`

When I click on my button,it does redirect me to main.html however there is nothing that happens (so it's undefined). I ve done several tests and the button works. Why is it not updating context.active?

Thank you.

Comment: What is `setActive{}` supposed to do ?

Comment: are you including  JS file 1 in HTML?

Comment: do both js files included in the html file (in the right order)?

Comment: setActive{} ? Is that supposed to be a function that assigns a value? If so, you are going about it the wrong way.

Comment: setActive is supposed to assign a value. And I did includ both files but I didn't know that the order matters

Comment: Looks more like a syntax error to me ?

Comment: @BarryChapman - Why would you edit the question and fix the errors in the OP's code ?

Comment: @adeneo: I thought about that after I did it, but I do not believe that is his only problem, there are other problems in his code. I did add the comment that I was operating on the assumption that he typed it up incorrectly. If he did in fact have this as his code verbatim, he would not have even got the alert. The fact that he DID receive an alert, leads me to believe that he has his code authored correctly in his script.

Comment: @BarryChapman - Who knows, but fixing errors in the question should be done by the OP, if you know what's wrong, post an answer.

Comment: I did post an answer. Besides, why do they give us the option to edit posts if it shouldn't be done by anyone but the OP? I firmly believe that he copied it incorrectly from his script to SO.

Comment: @user3475386 - can you make sure that the question accurately reflects the code you have in your script(s)?

Comment: @BarryChapman - There's nothing wrong with editing the question, but fixing the OP's code based on assumptions that it's not really the OP's code doesn't really sound like a good idea.

Comment: Yes, i modified my post because i didn't mention my other html file( big mistake).

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines, you need to check and account for certain situations.

JS File 1:

```
context = {};
```

Main HTML: (we are checking to make sure that context.active has been assigned. You will get an undefined message if context.active has not been assigned as a property of `context`)

```
function main() 
{ 
    if (typeof context.active != 'undefined')
       alert(context.active); 
}
```

JS File 2:

```
function setActive() { context.active=true; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The moment your browser redirects the Javascript variables are essentially erased.  A full page reload (redirect) results in a clean slate.

If you are trying to persist data on the client side across page loads then you will have to use either cookies or session storage.

document.cookie - [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie)

sessionStorage - [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage)

Each approach has it's pros and cons so be sure to read the docs and check support for these APIs in the browsers you plan to support.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea of how i could not lose the content of my variable?